# Arrange ten pawns into ten lines of three

Tags: visual, geometry, checkerboard

This is not a chess problem!

In the following position you can see six pawns that have been arranged into lines of three.  Each pawn stands at the intersection of exactly two lines and each line contains exactly three pawns.

For this problem 2 pawns don't count as a line.

[image]

Can you arrange ten pawns in such a way that each pawn is at the intersection of exactly three lines and each line contains exactly 3 pawns?

Each pawn must be positioned in the exact center of a square of a standard 8x8 chessboard.

Comment: The pawns should be in the center of a *tile* in a standard chessboard, right?

Comment: Oops!  Indeed.  Corrected.  I wanted to check if you people pay attention.  :-)

Comment: a line could also be drawn through the f7 and h3 pawns, only touching those two, but I think you meant that lines with < 3 pawns can be ignored.

Comment: Yes.  I am interested in alignments and 2 pawns don't count as an alignment.  I updated the question.

Comment: never mind, something was wrong with my vision I guess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's possible

> even on a 6x6 chessboard:
> [image]

EDIT:

> If we skew the previous solution we can obtain 6x5: 
> [image]

Comment: OK, nice, you could have made it a 6x5, but still good.

Comment: (after the update) OK, now I can admit I am impressed how fast you got it.

Comment: How? Did you just guess and check or what?

Comment: At first I ignored the chessboard and just thought about the incidence structure of pawns and lines. One possibility for this incidence structure is the Desargues configuration. So I placed various Desargues configurations onto the chessboard until they fit onto centers of squares.